# Blank Entry In Form - Don't Accept, Continue - powershell

Tags: powershell

My script checks AD for the user entered in the form. Accepts if found, rejects and asks again if not. I found that if the field is empty it will process it. I created a new option to not accept if .length -eq 0, then prompt and ask again. It continues to process the script and prompts again that the user account isn't found in AD. I need for the script to not make the second prompt, but rather to ask for a new entry.

```
function CreateXLS {

function ProcessOut ($x , $group) {
            $result = @()

            Foreach ($Line in $x){
                            $GroupName = "domain.local\" + $group
                            $OutList = New-Object System.Object
                            $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "DisplayPath_GroupName" -value $GroupName
                            $OutList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name "RuleName" -value "AutomaticApproval"

                            $result+= $OutList

  }
            #Output to XLS
            $outputfilepath = 'c:\users\admin\desktop\'
            $outputfilename = $outputfilepath + 'bulkupload.csv'
          $result | export-csv $outputfilename  -Append -encoding unicode -NoTypeInformation

  } 


 function PromptInput {
            add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
            Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing



            $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
            $form.Text = 'Group Auto-Approval Setup'
            $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,230)
            $form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

            $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
            $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(170,100)
            $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
            $OKButton.Text = 'OK'
            $OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
            $form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
            $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

            $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
            $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(260,100)
            $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
            $CancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
            $CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
            $form.CancelButton = $CancelButton    
            $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton) 




            $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
            $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,40)
            $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
            $label.Text = "Enter a group name:"
            $form.Controls.Add($label)

            $textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
            $textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,65)
            $textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,120)
            $form.Controls.Add($textBox)

            $form.Topmost = $true

            $form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
            $result = $form.ShowDialog()


      #Message box results: blank, found group, group doesn't exist.
           if($textbox.text -eq 0){[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::OK("Entry Cannot Be Blank, Continue?") , "Status" , 4)

           if ($result -eq 'Cancel'){
                            Exit
            }

            if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK){
                            $x = $textBox.Text
            }



            return $x


}






Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.visualbasic
$continue = $true
while($continue){
            $input = PromptInput


            $searcher = [ADSISearcher]"(SAMAccountName=$input)"
            $result = $searcher.FindOne()



            if($result){
                            ProcessOut $result $input
                            $additional = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to enter another group?" , "Status" , 4)
                            if ($additional -eq "NO"){
                                             createxls}
                            }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems I noticed in the area of `$textbox.text -eq 0`.  The check for `$textbox.text -eq 0` looks at the text contents instead of the length.  There is no static method `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::OK(...`.  Assuming this should be `[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(...`, the syntax is a little off.  The `}` appears to be missing at the end of that if block.

In the main part of the script, you are using `$input` for one of your variables.  This is an automatic variable and you should avoid using it as one of your variables (see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6)).  `continue` is a [reserved word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-6) so you may consider not using it as a variable name.  You also appear to have a continuous loop here, even after creating the output.

Replacing the bottom part of your code with this fragment should do what you want. It loops for user input until they cancel or choose not to continue.  This is main change.  Note the `ShowDialog()` is moved inside this loop.  Also note the variable name change and `$continue = $false` added in the main part of your script.

```
    # The rest of your script above stays the same

    $form.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
    #$result = $form.ShowDialog() # Moved to inside do..while $promptAgain loop

    #Message box results: blank, found group, group doesn't exist.
    $promptAgain = 'Yes'
    do {
        if ($promptAgain -eq 'Yes') {
            $result = $form.ShowDialog()
            $promptAgain = 'No'
        }
        if ($result -eq 'Cancel'){
            Exit
        }
        if ($textbox.text.Length -eq 0) {
            $promptAgain = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Entry Cannot Be Blank, Continue?" , "Status" , 4)
            if ($promptAgain -eq 'No'){
                Exit
            }
        }
    } while ($promptAgain -eq 'Yes')
    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK){
        $x = $textBox.Text
    }
    return $x
} # function PromptInput

Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.visualbasic
$continue = $true
while($continue) {
    $userInput = PromptInput

    $searcher = [ADSISearcher]"(SAMAccountName=$userInput)"
    $result = $searcher.FindOne()

    if($result){
        ProcessOut $result $userInput
        $additional = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Would you like to enter another group?" , "Status" , 4)
        if ($additional -eq "NO"){
            createxls
            $continue = $false # added to be able to exit while($continue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Works perfect.